# Simple preg_match with capturing groups, where I'am wrong?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Filenames:

```
forms.it.yml
validators.en.xliff
```

I need to extract three pieces (from filenames): `<domain>.<locale>.<format>`, so I ended up with this regex:

```
/^(?P<domain>\.+).(?P<locale>\w{2,}).(?P<format>\w+)$/
```

But of course it's not working. There should be something obvious I'm missing.

```php
$match = '/^(?P<domain>\.+).(?P<locale>\w{2,}).(?P<format>\w+)$/';
$subject = 'forms.it.yml';

var_dump(preg_match($match, $subject)); // 0
```

Comment: or do you just mean the filenames here?

Comment: @hakre filenames, sorry. Not parsing XML.

Comment: if that is multi-line you need to tell [PCRE via the multi-line modifier: `m` (PCRE_MULTILINE)](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers)

Comment: @hakre plese remove the close flag (if possible), thank you.

Comment: Not possible to remove, it will time-out (it actually takes 4 votes for on-hold and then it can be re-opened, in case you get on hold with this, just comment and let me know, I mis-read your question)

Comment: You are also perhaps looking for: `list($domain, $locale, $format) = explode('.', $subject) + [NULL, NULL, NULL];` or http://php.net/sscanf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot is special in your pattern. Make it unspecial by either putting into square brackets or by slashing it. So the dot is a dot verbatim.

And as you do that already with the first dot, you need to change that, too, but I suggest you exclude it from the pattern to match otherwise - if greedy - this might not work well. And it is often greedy by default.

```
/^(?P<domain>[^.]+)\.(?P<locale>[a-zA-Z]{2,})\.(?P<format>\w+)$/
             ##### ^^           ########     ^^
               ^   dot              ^        dot
               |                    |
            not dot      just a little variation
```

Example/[Demo](https://eval.in/46153):

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/18546468/367456
 */

$match = '/^(?P<domain>[^.]+)\\.(?P<locale>[a-zA-Z]{2,})\\.(?P<format>\\w+)$/';
$subject = 'forms.it.yml';

var_dump(preg_match($match, $subject)); // int(1)
```

Program Output:

```
int(1)
```

Further optimization is possible by using [*Possessive Quantifiers*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html):

```
/^(?P<domain>[^.]++)\.(?P<locale>[a-zA-Z]{2,}+)\.(?P<format>\w++)$/
                  ^                          ^                 ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have escaped your first dot and not the intermediate dots.

Your first group (`domain`) is matching `\.+` which matches one or more literal dots greedily.

The intermediate pattern `.` is a regex dot so matches everything.

You want to change the escaped dot to a *not* dot pattern using a negated character class. I also suggest you make use of the possessive quantifier to speed up failing with non-matching text:

```
^(?P<domain>[^.]++)\.(?P<locale>[^.]{2,}+)\.(?P<format>.*+)$
```